# MySQL scheduler not running Yearly

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have created a MySQL scheduler that will update the table with new data every year. I change my current date and time to 31/12/2020 11:59:00pm to see if the scheduler working or not. Unfortunately, the table is not updating after it passes 1/1/2021 00:00:00. But when I try to schedule for every minute without changing my time, the scheduler working fine. Is my SQL not correct?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT duplicate_public_holiday
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' YEAR
STARTS '2021-01-01 00:00:00'
    DO
      BEGIN
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp SELECT `CalHID`, `CalDDate`, `CalDName`, `CalDTitle`, `CalDYear`, `IsActive`, `IsDeleted`, `CreatedBy`, `CreatedDate`, `CreatedTime`, `ModifiedBy`,`ModifiedDate`, `ModifiedTime`, `DeletedBy`, `DeletedDate`, `DeletedTime`
        FROM tbcalendardetail WHERE CalDYear=(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR), "%Y")) AND IsActive=1 AND IsDeleted=0;

        UPDATE tmp SET CalDYear=(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y"));
        UPDATE tmp SET CreatedDate=(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y-%m-%d"));
        UPDATE tmp SET CreatedTime=(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%h:%i:%s"));

        INSERT INTO tbcalendardetail (`CalHID`, `CalDDate`, `CalDName`, `CalDTitle`, `CalDYear`, `IsActive`, `IsDeleted`, `CreatedBy`, `CreatedDate`, `CreatedTime`, `ModifiedBy`, `ModifiedDate`, `ModifiedTime`, `DeletedBy`, `DeletedDate`, `DeletedTime`) 
        SELECT * FROM tmp;

        DROP TABLE tmp;
      END$$
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: Check is MySQL time changed according system time: `SELECT NOW():`

Comment: yes, it follows the system time.